# Wiring diagram and phase number of three phase transformer

Tags: transformer, three-phase, diagram

Does anybody have an idea how to draw vector diagram of primary and secondary of a three phase transformer? For instance, if I need to draw vector diagram for Yzn5 diagram and then also draw the winding connections? All I know is that primary is in star connection, secondary in interconnected star and the phase between voltages is 150 degrees (5*30). Also, how to determine this vice-versa (phase number) from an already drawn transformer windings. Is there a good book or internet source covering this field? Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you have a specific problem you need help with or do you just want resources to learn more about vector/winding diagrams of three phase systems? You start out asking for general knowledge stuff, then mention specific values as if you have a problem you need to solve, then ask for resources to study. If you want both study materials and help with a specific problem, _use separate paragraphs_... Also for the specific problem please share a copy of the problem.

Comment: I just used specific problem as an aid to explain what I need. I do not help with specific problem (yet), I need (as you stated) "resources to study". Thanks!

Comment: The IEC standard for transformers, IEC 60076, covers this in detail. Try [IEC 60076.1 *Power Transformers - Part 1 - General*](http://infostore.saiglobal.com/store/Details.aspx?productID=1464466). The section you want is under "Connection Symbols".